# codeigniter join and session

Tags: codeigniter, join

I'm trying make a chat app for my website..But i can't take the messages for member who login..Session is not working with join..How can i fix it ?

My model

public function masajlarigoster(){

```
$_session=$this->session->userdata('logged_in');

$query=$this->db->query('select cekid.cekId,mesajlar.* 
    from cekid left join mesajlar on (mesajlar.kimId=$_session->Id 
        and mesajlar.kimeId=cekid.cekId) 
        or (mesajlar.kimId=cekid.cekId 
            and mesajlar.kimeId=$_session->Id)  '); 


    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->result();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$_SESSION is a protected global. You are also trying to use an array as an object...

You can use the query builder for this if you have it enabled (disclaimer: i haven't tested this and have done it from memory)

```
$loggedin = $this->session->get_userdata('logged_in');
$query = $this->db->select('cekid.cekId,mesajlar.*')
    ->from('cekid')
    ->join('mesajlar','mesajlar.kimeId=cekid.cekId','left')
    ->group_start()
        ->where('mesajlar.kimId', $loggedin)
        ->or_group_start()
            ->where('mesajlar.kimId', 'cekid.cekId')
            ->where('mesajlar.kimeId', $loggedin)
        ->group_end() 
    ->group_end() 
    ->get();

if($query->num_rows() > 0){
    return $query->result();
}else{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: if you do a `print_r($this->session->get_userdata());` do you get any results?

Comment: $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('cekid');
   $this->db->join('mesajlar', 'cekid.cekId =            mesajlar.kimeId');
   $this->db->where("kimId",$_session->Id)
   $query = $this->db->get();

Comment: session works with this but i cant use and command with join here

Comment: don't use $_session, as its protected. I updated your syntax in my answer

Comment: I'm not sure of your answer before... if you aren't getting results from the `print_r($this->session->get_userdata());` then you have no session data set, so you are trying to get something to use in the WHERE that doesn't exist. Enable sessions and set the parameters...

Comment: Brian thanks for your update but it doesn't work too..I can get information with print_r($this->session->get_userdata()); but your query doesnt work :(